# Deploying python site to production server

Tags: python, django, git, deployment

I have django website in testing server and i am confused with how should the deployement procedure goes.

Locally i have these folders

```
code
virtualenv
static
static/app/bower_components
node_modules
```

Current on git i only have code folder in there.

My Initial thought was to do this on production server

```
git clone repo
pip install
npm install 
bower install
colectstatic
```

But i had this problem that sometimes some components in `pip or npm or bowel` fail to install and then production deployemnet fails.

I was thinking of put everything in static, bower, npm etc inside git so that i can fetch all in prodcution.

Is that the right way to do. i want to know the right way to tackle that problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i had this problem that sometimes some components in pip or npm or
>   bowel fail to install and then production deployment fails.

There is no solution for this other than to find out why things are failing in production (or a way around would be to not install anything in production, just copy stuff over).

I would caution against the second option because Python virtual environments are not designed to be portable. If you have components such as PIL/Pillow or database drivers, these need system libraries to be installed and compiled against at build time.

Here is what I would recommend, which is in-line with the [deployment section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/) in the documentation:

1. Create an updated requirements file (pip freeze > requirements.txt)
2. Run collectstatic on your testing environment.
3. Move the static directory to your frontend/proxy machine, and map it to `STATIC_URL`. Confirm this works by browsing the static URL (for example: http://example.com/static/images/logo.png)
4. Clone/copy your codebase to the production server.
5. Create a blank virtual environment.
6. Install dependencies with `pip install -r requirements.txt`
7. Make sure you [run through the deployment checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/), which includes security tips and settings you need to enable for production.

After this point, you can bring up your django server using your favorite method.

There are [many, many guides](https://www.google.com/search?q=deployment+guidelines+django) on deploying django and many are customized for particular environments (for example, AWS automation, Heroku deployment tips, Digital Ocean, etc.)  You can browse those for ideas (I usually pick out any automation tips) but be careful adopting one strategy without making sure it works with your particular environment/requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the info . when you say `not install anything in production, just copy stuff over` what does that mean. isn't it same as put everything in  git. because this was what we currently doing :)

Comment: You only put things in git that require version control. I personally do not use it for "copying things over".

Comment: I was thinking to have separate repo for production . All the stuff which is tested on testing server will get pushed to that repo and that will get deployed in production including all assets etc. Is there anything wrong in that approach provided the production and testing are exact replica of servers

Comment: Now you just created another problem of maintaining two repositories. Use branches and tags instead; and one repository.

Comment: I thought that but then my normal 50MB repo will become 800MB even if we drop that idea in future that size will never reduce

Comment: Why is a 800 MB repository a problem? You'll have the same headache if you have two repositories, except now you have one 50 MB one and the other 800 MB.

Answer (score 0):

In addition [this](http://www.fullstackpython.com/deployment.html) might be helpful for some guidelines on deployment.